# CSOM + SharePoint Online: getTaxonomySession returns null

Tags: csom, taxonomy

I'm trying to use this fairly straightforward code:

```
function getAllTerms() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    SP.SOD.executeFunc("SP.Taxonomy.js", 'SP.ClientContext', function () {

        //Current Taxonomy Session
        var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
        console.log(taxSession);
        //Term Stores
        var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();
        //Name of the Term Store from which to get the Terms.
        var termStore = termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_Pu0HiX4GZKMCNnSDgo8P3g==");
        //GUID of Term Set from which to get the Terms.
        var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("99197470-943b-43d1-8375-209fb75251f6");
        var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();

        context.load(terms);
        context.executeQueryAsync(function () {

            var termEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
            var termList = "Terms: \n";
            while (termEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var currentTerm = termEnumerator.get_current();
                termList += currentTerm.get_name() + "\n";
            }
            alert(termList);
        }, function (sender, args) {
            console.log(args.get_message());
        });
    });
}
```

But whether I try to use getByName or getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore, I always get the error:

```
Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object returned by the following call stack is null. "GetTermSet
GetByName
TermStores
Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession
```

I know there's a possible configuration change in Central Administration to carry out with SharePoint 2013, but this is SharePoint Online, so surely this should just work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to the portal using SharePoint admin credentials.

After that, go to the below url:

```
https://yourtenantname-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/termstoremanager.aspx
```

It will open the term store in the admin site.

Now go to the term set in the term store.

Ensure that `available for tagging` check box is checked as below. After that save the termset.

[image]

It should work now.

If the error still persists, try the below refactored code:

```
var termSetId = "99197470-943b-43d1-8375-209fb75251f6"; 

var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
var termStore = taxonomySession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
var termSet = termStore.getTermSet(termSetId);
var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();
```

Comment: Ha. I already had "Available for tagging" enabled, but I was using the guid of the parent group instead of the term set itself, and your screenshot pointed me towards that. Thank you!